# laravel get the index from Select instead of te viewed value

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Form::select drop down and am filling it from a table in my database.
I want to get the index of the select because I want to save it in the database.

This is my view

```
{!! Form::open(["url"=>"devices" ,"files"=>"true"]) !!}
Name :  {!! Form::text("device_name") !!}  
Category: {!! Form::select('category', $categories) !!}
```

and in the controller I tried to use `key($array)`, but it gave me a null value:

```
$device_name = $request->input('device_name');
//$device_category = $request->input('device_category');
$device_category = $request->input('key(category)');
$device_company = $request->input('device_company');
$device_description = $request->input('device_description');
$device_price = $request->input('device_price');


$file= $request->file('image');
$destpath = 'img';
$file_name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
$file->move($destpath,$file_name);

$new_device = new Devices;

$new_device->device_name = $device_name;
$new_device->device_category = $device_category;
$new_device->device_company = $device_company;
$new_device->device_description = $device_description;
$new_device->device_price = $device_price;
$new_device->device_imgURL = "\img\\" . $file_name;

$new_device->save();
```

How can I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this the following to get array of categories and use in select box

```
$categories = Category::pluck('title', 'id');
```

Select box

```
{!! Form::select('category', $categories, null, ['class' => 'some-class']) !!}
```

And you can get category id in controller using

```
$request->category
```

Answer (score 0):

in your controller you get category value by `$device_category = $request->input('category');`

if you want to set value then you need to pass associatve array as second parameter or else form select set defualt index 0 ,1,2...

```
{{ Form::select('age', [
   'young' => 'Under 18',
   'adult' => '19 to 30',
   'adult2' => 'Over 30']
) }}
```

This will use the keys for the option values.

```
<select name="age">
  <option value="young">Under 18</option>
  <option value="adult">19 to 30</option>
  <option value="adult2">Over 30</option>
</select>
```